# hibernate fail to alter table when table having huge records

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

application deployment is getting failed due to hibernate alter query applying on table. Table is having huge data. Having spring boot application.

Comment: What do you mean with "alter query"?

Comment: I am adding one column in table by hibernate. But table is having huge data and unfortunately,Spring boot application is getting failed. How to handle it while starting?